# what is the best way to change a Git repo's origin?

Tags: git

I cloned a read-only Git repo from GitHub onto my server.  The next day, I forked that repo on GitHub.  What are the steps to update the remotes on my repository and make sure everything on the server is up-to-date?

Is this the way to start?  Is there anything else I need to to so that the clone will treat the new origin as if I had originally cloned from it?

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/fork.git
```

Comment: good catch - corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The repository as a whole doesn't have such a setting – each individual local branch does; there is a per-branch setting for its "upstream" or "tracking" branch which acts as the default for pushing, merging, or the @{u} shortcut.

The preferred way to change it is via the `-u` option of `git push` or `git branch`:

- Just change upstream branch:

  ```
  git branch -u origin/master master
  ```
- Or, push to a remote branch *and* set it as the new upstream:

  ```
  git push -u origin master
  ```

It can also be done directly through repository configuration (which is how it used to be done before `-u` was implemented):

- ```
  git config branch.master.remote origin
  ```